# Trying to fix this error message "Invalid authentication method set in configuration: coookie" on the - phpMyAdmin page, when using MAMP?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mamp

I just restarted MAMP after months to start using it with Wordpress. Apache and MySQL Servers are both running fine (are green) and the start page launches fine. However the phpMyAdmin page is giving an error message:

**phpMyAdmin - Error**

> Invalid authentication method set in configuration: coookie

[For what it's worth - I've cleared the browser cache ond cookies and have found negligible relevant material (solutions) around the issue, so far.]

Any known steps to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one "o" too many in your coookie (check your PhpMyAdmin configuration file).

Comment: That was it! In case anyone else stumbles upon it - just had to edit the file, clear the cache, and refresh/restart the browser.

Comment: Whoops, I had to clear my cache as well in my browser, thanks!